# AutoResetEvent and await

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous

I want to wait for an event signal from another thread without blocking the waiting thread. Ideally using await.

I thought of this solution:

```
        await Task.Run(() => myAutoResetEvent.WaitOne());
```

I would like to know if there is something conceptually wrong with it and if there are better alternatives

Thanks!

Comment: Are you getting an error? Which error is?

Comment: No, no errors. Just wondering if there is some conceptual error I am missing. I clarified a bit the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What is wrong with doing this?

You're using a thread pool thread just to wait for a "signal".

> what is a better alternative?

You can use an async-compatible `AutoResetEvent`, such as the one in [my AsyncEx library](https://github.com/StephenCleary/AsyncEx) or the one on [Stephen Toub's blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/02/11/10266923.aspx).

Also, most of the time auto reset events are the wrong thing to use. manual reset events are much more common. I'd recommend re-evaluating this choice of synchronization primitive.